# install tool chain for uClinux

Tags: 14.10

I want to install arm-elf-tools-20030314.sh

```
sudo sh arm-elf-tools-20030314.sh
```

but i got this error

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Answer (score 0):

This error appears to be the result of a [change in the POSIX conformance](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2009-05/msg00074.html) of the `tail` command used in the script portion of the `arm-elf-tools-20030314.sh` file to determine the start of the binary archive portion of the file. It seems to be possible to work around it by defining the environment variable `_POSIX2_VERSION=199209` e.g.

```
sudo _POSIX2_VERSION=199209 sh arm-elf-tools-20030314.sh
```

**However note that due to the apparent age of this software you may have other compatibility issues.**